# comparing 2 values of json array element in where clause

Tags: postgresql-9.3, jsonb

Here is my scenario. I have my application installed on a computer. I have an environment variable which tells me which drive the application is installed. I also have information about each drive available in the system, the total space of the drive and the available disk space. All these information is stored in postgres as jsonb. I have to write a query to output the details of the system and only fetch the details of the drive where my application is installed.

Json application home path

[image]

Drive information

[image]

This is my sample code

```
SELECT json_data->>'Systemname' as SystemName, 
json_data ->> 'ApplicationHomePath'as ApplicationHome,
(jsonb_array_elements(json_data -> 'systemInformation' -> 'storage') -> 'capacity'->>'size') as capacity,
(jsonb_array_elements(json_data -> 'systemInformation' -> 'storage') -> 'available'->>'size') as availablesize,
(jsonb_array_elements(json_data -> 'systemInformation' -> 'storage') ->>'driveLetter') as drive 
FROM json;
```

The current output will give me 2 rows for one system if the system has 2 drive and the corresponding information. What I need it to do is give me the result of the drive which is equal to the drive where my application is installed. Basically I want the value to be compared with the ApplicationHomePath and if it matches, give me the output of that.